# Android-Chrome - Discrepency between PHPSSID cookie value and session ID

Tags: php, android, session, session-cookies

I am building a website in php which uses sessions. **Sessions** **work fine on my computer** using Chrome, Firefox or Opera, **but don't on my Android phone** (with Chrome). To try figuring out what the problem was, I added that code at the top of login page (right before the HTML tag):

```
   if (isset($_COOKIE["__Host-SSID"])){
       $cookieSSID=$_COOKIE["__Host-SSID"];
    }else{
       $cookieSSID="NoCookie";
    }

    echo(session_id()."_".$cookieSSID);
```

And I followed those 5 steps which shows 4 times the login page:

1. Delete all cookies and reload the login page for a fresh start
2. Reload the login page => Should not change SSID
3. Log in => A new SSID is generated
4. Log out => A new SSID is generated. The logout page redirect to the login page
5. Reload the login page

Here are examples of what I see echoed at the top of the login page.
On the computer, it works as expected (I shortened the SSID for clarity sake):

1. 435e8f6_NoCookie    => All good
2. 435e8f6_**435e8f6** => All good
3. d3c4dc9_**d3c4dc9** => All good
4. d3c4dc9_**d3c4dc9** => All good

Now, on the phone, here is what it shows :

1. bf95d66_NoCookie    => All good
2. bf95d66_bf95d66 => All good
3. 8ab6e12_8ab6e12=> All good
4. **c75aa41_**4eca36c**=> THERE, TROUBLE COMES**

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else: I solved the problem using the phone debugging mode. It had nothing to do with php or Chrome but with my SQL database that was misconfigured.